# PHP Transfer of variables from one page to another

Tags: php, variables, transfer

I got my first PHP form working, and it submits to the database before returning to the form.  But the form does not reflect the submitted values.  I remember how to inject dynamic HTML based on PHP variables, but my understanding is that first there is a way to transfer php variable values from one page to another.  How do you do this?  Here is the end of my submission page, just in case it helps.

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE administration SET ac1= ?, ac2= ?, fan= ?, na= ?, dh= ?, tolerance1= ?, temptime1= ?, tolerance2= ?, temptime2= ?, tolerance3= ?, temptime3= ?, tolerance4= ?, temptime4= ?, tolerance5= ?, temptime5= ?, humidtolerance1= ?, humidtime1= ?, humidtolerance2= ?,  humidtime2= ?, humidtolerance3= ?,  humidtime3= ?, humidtolerance4= ?,  humidtime4= ?, humidtolerance5= ?,  humidtime5= ? WHERE custnum = ?"); 
$STH->execute(array($ac1, $ac2, $fan, $na, $dh, $tolerance1, $temptime1, $tolerance2, $temptime2, $tolerance3, $temptime3, $tolerance4, $temptime4, $tolerance5, $temptime5, $humidtolerance1, $humidtime1, $humidtolerance2, $humidtime2, $humidtolerance3, $humidtime3, $humidtolerance4, $humidtime4, $humidtolerance5, $humidtime5, $custnum));


$STH->execute();  

//Send them back to the page they were at/
header("location:index.php");
```

Comment: Technically, there is no way to transfer PHP variables between two pages, because PHP does not know any Page object - it only knows a request. You might want to display the form pre-filled with data from the database you just stored?

Answer (score 2):

Use super global variables to pass the data from one page to another. There are many but some of the most popular are:

1. [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

   Pass the data in the form of url `page.php?variable=value` and 
   read the values as `echo $_GET['variable']
2. [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

   Pass the data using `<form method="POST">...</form>`
   and read the values as `echo $_POST['variable']`
3. [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

   1. Start the session `session_start();`
   2. Declare a variable `$_SESSION['variable'] = "value";`
   3. Read the value `echo $_SESSION['variable'];`
4. [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

   1. Declare a variable `$_SERVER['variable'] = "value";`
   2. Read the value `echo $_SERVER['variable'];`

Each of the above methods are fit in their own cases. To read more go [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Answer (score 0):

While in your case there might be better ways to achieve the overall goal, to answer your question, you can transfer variables between pages for the same user with sessions.

See the PHP manual entries:

http://il.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

http://il.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php